# HttpResponse Transmit File - stopping following code

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I have an asp.net button which calls this method.

```
 protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Clear();
            string filePath = getFilePath();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FvGReport.xlsx");
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
            Response.End();
            newReportMessage.Visible = false;
        }
```

But the newReportMessage.Visible component is never able to run. Through reading around I could see that Response.End() just terminates the thread and so that made sense. So I have tried what seems to work for a lot of other people.

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Clear();
            string filePath = getFilePath();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FvGReport.xlsx");
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.SuppressContent = true;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

            newReportMessage.Visible = false;
        }
```

But it still doesn't work? Does anyone know what the problem is so I can avoid this in the future, and what is the solution?